# Ocean Plug-in expires on?

Tags: ocean

How to define the expiration date to Ocean/Petrel plug-ins? 
This expiration date is showed in the plug-in manager of Petrel, "expires on:".

Answer (score 2):

There is no Ocean API to obtain the expiration date for a given Ocean plug-in.

Moreover, this field does not work in Petrel 2011 Plug-in Manager, and it always displays "N/A" in "Expires on:" field.